# Handling endpoints APIs on client side instead of serverMiddleware in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, express, nuxt.js, electron-builder, prisma

I'm on Nuxt 2.15.8 and trying to build an offline app with electron.js and prisma+sqlite for local DB.

In nuxt to hit a local endpoint there is a common way of using serverMiddleware and express like this:

```js
// api.js that will be added to nuxt.config.js file as serverMiddleware
import express from 'express'
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

export default {
  path: '/api',
  handler: app
}
```

which send endpoints beginning with `api/` through `app` handler which I can use to access my BD (the common way to access sqlite3 DB is the same)

```js
// added to api.js
import { PrismaClient } from '../../resources/prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()
app.get(`/user/info`, async (req, res) => {
  const result = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: 1,
    },
  })
  console.console.log(res);
  res.json(result)
})
```

this will work fine on nuxt, also fine on nuxt-electron `dev` mode. but on built `exe` file serverMiddleware won't be called. So as it has be done by others (nuxt-electron accessing offline local DB) there must be a way to define endpoints on client side. any idea??

**Updated:**

as I changed my Nuxt-Electron boilerplate I could access serverMiddleware in `exe` file but it wont hit the endpoints yet!

Comment: do you have the endpoint handlers inside exe file?

Comment: @Amaarrockz , by exe file , you mean `resources` folder and `asar unpacked` right? no , it's not there. the api handler is a nuxt serverMiddleware file and must be bundled with nuxt

Comment: Have you tried the [proxy module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module)? It uses [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) which allows custom router functions.

Comment: @RWAM , no , will check that definitely!

Comment: @RWAM , well ... checked that and first of all it won't work with nuxt generate ! also it's kinda work like reverse proxy on server! and won't accept a handler to do some functions! just changing the endpoint url